# Call to MongoRepository in an ExecutorService fails to complete

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, threadpool

I am running a Spring Boot application and have multiple threads calling a MongoRepository. This, however, leads to weird timeout behavior.

This is my MongoRepository:

```
public interface EquipmentRepository extends MongoRepository<Equipment, String> {

    Optional<Equipment> findByEquipmentSerialNumber(String equipmentSerialNumber);

}
```

This is a reduced version of my code highlighting the problem

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
    LOG.info("Executing query...");
    Optional<Equipment> equipment = equipmentRepository.findByEquipmentSerialNumber("21133"); // guaranteed to be found
    LOG.info("Query done: {}", equipment.get().getEquipmentSerialNumber());
});
taskExecutor.shutdown();
LOG.info("taskExecutor shut down");
try {
    taskExecutor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    LOG.info("taskExecutor done");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

That produced output looks like this

```
taskExecutor shut down
Executing query...
<30 second pause>
taskExecutor done
Query done: 21133
```

If I increase the timeout of awaitTermination() the pause increases accordingly. So somehow my code inside the execute() lambda is "paused" and only continues after the timeout is reached.

If I remove the call to equipmentRepository, everything works as expected and there is no 30-second pause.

What is keeping my code from completing without reaching the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like mongo repository waits for 'main' thread to perform query (very strange though)

Not answer for your specific question, but probably solution for your problem: Spring Data can do async requests [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async)